# Manipulate the 3D Axis Locally

Tags: 3d-manipulator

How can I change or manipulate the Global 3D Space?..  I know if I click on Local it will change and I can move parts on the axis I need to but I can't rotate. Lever's, Hoses.. all in different areas around the part I need to animate to show functionality. Earlier I just rotated the machine to where I needed to animate a part on a particular axis. Trying to avoid that. [image]

Comment: In the *Properties Shelf* (`N` Key) in the 3D view there s a panel called *Transform Orientations*. There you can create any custom coordinate systems that you desire and use them freely.

Comment: Right, and you can just choose from the choices in red-circled dialog box.. and there's an option to Create Orientation that pops-up on the opposite side of screen (T Key).  So I create one called "Jerry Rigged", and I can check on "Use View" "Use after Creation" or "Overwrite Previous".